# Error while setting up local cluster with service fabric SDK version 2.1.150.X

Tags: azure, service

While creating local cluster with latest service fabric SDK, I got following errors with **Visual Studio 2013 Update 5** while it works fine with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3:

```
Cluster manifest validation failed with exception System.ArgumentException: Error occurs in section Federation, parameter System.
Fabric.Management.ServiceModel.SettingsOverridesTypeSectionParameter...
OR
Cluster manifest validation failed with exception System.ArgumentException: Section FaultAnalysisService found in cluster manifest but not Configurations.csv in system.fabric.management.dll
```

**What I did to fix it?**

If you closely look into error, you will find that following two files settings are not compatible.
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code\Configurations.csv
and 
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure\ClusterManifestTemplate.xml

Just disable following in ClusterManifestTemplate.xml:

```
<Section Name="Federation">
       <Parameter Name="NodeIdGeneratorVersion" Value="V3" />
        <!-- <Parameter Name="UnresponsiveDuration" Value="0" /> -->
</Section>
and 
<!-- <Section Name="FaultAnalysisService">
        <Parameter Name="TargetReplicaSetSize" Value="5" />
        <Parameter Name="MinReplicaSetSize" Value="3" />
</Section> -->
```

Comment: Above of my solution let me create cluster in my local. Let me know if we have any other way where we can just install Service fabric SDK and run DevClusterSetup.ps1 without any change to complete cluster setup.